# Finding the source code for Eval Monad, rseq or rpar

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am unable to find the source code for Eval Monad in ghc-7.10.2. to see what is under the hood.  The ":i rseq" command points to Control.Parallel.Strategies.  But neither manual search nor findstr bring up anything.

Comment: You can use hoogle and click "source" for this kind of things: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.1.0/docs/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#t:Eval  Keep in mid this will be low-level code, also involving the GHC runtime -- it can be quite scary.

Comment: I usually use hoogle/hadock to search for it ... if I do I find [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.1.0/docs/src/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#rseq)

Comment: `Eval` is defined the same as `IO`, actually. I don't know why it's not just a `newtype`. I opened an issue asking them to make it one, but they didn't like that idea for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

As @chi answered, you an go to the [haddocks on hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.1.0/docs/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html), and then click the "source" link.

You can also go to the [main page](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.1.0) on hackage, and then click the browse link next to "downloads" which brings up a [listing of the tar contents](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.1.0/src/). And finally you can click the source repository link, which brings up the [github page](https://github.com/haskell/parallel).